# Symfony 3: Doctrine stores NULL values in database

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-forms

Symfony Version: 3.1.3

I have a controller like below,

```
public function studentAddClassAction( $id, Request $request )
{
    $em     = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $student= new Student();

    // new class object and create the form
    $classes= $em->getRepository('PIE10Bundle:Classes')->findAll();
    $form   = $this->createForm(ClassType::class, $classes);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if( $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() )
    {   
        $parent = $form['parent']->getData(); // the parentID
        $cName  = $form['class']->getData();
        $classID= $cName->getId(); // the classID

        //insert new row to the student table
        $student->setParentId( $parent );
        $student->setClassId( $classID );
        $student->setUserId( $id );

        $em->persist($student);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('notice',
                        'Student Updated');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_students');
    }
    // some other code
}
```

Further if I run,

```
if( $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() )
{   
    $parent = $form['parent']->getData(); // the parentID
    $cName  = $form['class']->getData();
    $classID= $cName->getId(); // the classID

    echo $parent . ' / ' . $classID . ' / ' . $id;
    die;
    // ...
```

it gives the expected values - for an example `17 / 6 / 5` or the related result correctly which means I am getting all `$parent`, `$classID` and `$id` into the `if( $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() )` condition

But when I try to insert them by using the,

```
$student->setParentId( $parent );
$student->setClassId( $classID );
$student->setUserId( $id );

$em->persist($student);
$em->flush();
```

it store the row like below in the

[image]

with **NULL** values for **classId** and **userId** columns but it sets only the **parentId** and setter methods are below in the **Student** entity

```
public function setParentId($parentId)
{
    $this->parentId = $parentId;

    return $this;
}

public function setClassId($classId)
{
    $this->classId = $classId;

    return $this;
}

public function setUserId($userId)
{
    $this->userId = $userId;

    return $this;
}
```

This is little bit strange for me and want fix this. Please let me know if any other dev information is needed.

Thanks

**Update**

```
class Student
{
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Classes", inversedBy="student")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="classId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $classes;

/**
 * Get classes
 *
 * @return \PIE10Bundle\Entity\Classes
 */
public function getClasses()
{
    return $this->classes;
}

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Users", inversedBy="student")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id" )
 */
private $users;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="userId", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $userId;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", unique=true)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="parentId", type="integer")
 */
private $parentId;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="classId", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $classId;
```

Comment: Can you show annotations of Entity properties?

Comment: @alex_kalenyuk please check the Update section for annotations

Comment: did you try something like $student->setClassId(5)?

Comment: @DmitryMalyshenko is correct with his answer. You should seriously consider reading the Doctrine2 ORM documentation before you continue.

Comment: Thanks for this. will continue with his answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why would you assign IDs to an entity?
Working with ORM (any, not only Doctrine) you should not operate with IDs, but with objects and models.

So, do not ever code

```
$student->setParentId( $parent );
$student->setClassId( $classID );
$student->setUserId( $id );
```

Instead, you should make

```
$student->setParent($parent);
$student->setClass($class);
$student->setUser($user);
```

Where `$parent`, `$class` and `$users` - related entities. If it's mapped correctly, then it will be persisted correctly.

Also, it's obviously a misuse of Symfony Form. If you only want to add a student to class, you should not persist a new object of the student. When you make `$form->submit()`, to class's `ArrayCollection` of students will be added a new instance of student (which you are willing to add), and then `persist()` will persist the class, and (if you add `cascade="persist"`) all users as well.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. really informative for my first Symfony project